# How to Search Faster way Inside Favorite Question Tab?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, search, favorites-tab

I am having  difficulties while searching questions from the Favorite Questions Tab.

Is there any way to get out of this. It pretty difficult to go through each and every question what we are looking for.

Also is it possible to get the search result inside the Favorite Tab, if the questions matches the favorites?

Comment: This is hard to understand. Can you clean this up to explain what you really want? Right now, if searching inside a question, use Ctrl+F

Comment: Thnks for editing in my question. any support will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the [`favorites` tab](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LROTS.png) inside your profile?

Comment: @brasofilo : yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there is no feature to search inside the favorite question tab. This is how I search from my favorite questions tab:

1. First of all decide the way to sort the questions list.

   - votes: If you think the question is highly upvoted, sort by votes
   - activity: If you think the question is recently activated, sort by activity
   - newest: If you think the question is newer, sort by newest
   - views: If you think the question has more views, sort by views
   - added: If you think the question is recently favorited by you, sort by added
2. Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (i.e. searching feature of the browser) and enter some text you think it should be in question's title. If you find the question, you are lucky. If no go to next page and search again.
3. Some tips:

   - If you think the question may be available after some pages then go to that page and start searching.
   - You can also search for tag name if it is rarely used tag. But don't search for tag which is often used like SQL, C#, Java etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can once again use the `infavorites:mine` operator with search, like this:

[infavorites:mine](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites%3Amine), then just add whatever terms you want to search for.